# Why are the proofs in math texts not written in a way that a human might discover them?

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing

I read about the complete solution of Pythagorean triples (integers $a, b, c$ such that $a^2+b^2=c^2$) in *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving* by Paul Zeitz and the solution was presented in a way that someone might've discovered it; it was excellent and showing me how I might approach and prove Diophantine equations on my own.

Then I went back to my Number Theory book from university and read the solution; it was terse, and after reading it I don't feel any wiser about how to solve other Diophantine equations.

If the aim of the proofs is not to help the students learn *how* to prove theorems, then why are the proofs even in the book? Just to convince the reader that the theorems are true? Personally I would be satisfied with taking the author's word for it.

P.S. I'm talking about undergraduate books.

Comment: some topics are broader than others and some books are meant to be broader than others.

Comment: I'd guess it's simply because spending time using exposition that shows "how to discover it" is very challenging to write, and perhaps risks trying the patience of the reader. The "easy way out" of both of these problems is to fall back on "backdoor" proofs.

Comment: @rschwieb Are you aware of any introductory texts which are written in this style? I know *Visual Complex Analysis* is a good one that roughly has this style, but I am wondering about other branches of math as well.

Comment: There could be many reasons. One is that with experience one learns how to distill the arguments in a terse proof so as to learn a lot from it, and it is often better for one to decipher a proof for themselves rather than have somebody present the argument in an elaborate way for them. Granted, this is a challenge and an important skill to develop. Another reason could be for a show off effect.

Comment: IMO the terseness of a proof is tailored to the expected proficiency of the audience. In a text book I'd expect proofs to be a little beyond the proficiency of the audience since the textbook's goal is to increase proficiency. A number theory textbook's proof would, under this theory, be somewhat beyond an audience who has the background to take number theory. But the Zeitz book appears intended for a more general, hence less proficient audience. Additionally the focus of textbook is on number theory vs a book whose focus is on problem solving.

Comment: @Ovi Although I have never read it, but I have assurances that [Creative mathematics by H. S. Wall](https://books.google.com/books?id=LDPT0H_XQY8C&dq=Creative+mathematics+H.+S.+Wall&lr=&source=gbs_navlinks_s) is exactly of that type.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/13089/why-do-so-many-textbooks-have-so-much-technical-detail-and-so-little-enlightenme